# Python Outlook (MAPI) Get Response Time of Mails Replied

Tags: python, outlook

I was using the `ConversationID` of the mails in the `Inbox` and the mails in the `Sent Items`, assuming that the IDs will be same for the mails that we replied to, **and it is same** but the problem begins with Email Chains (or the Re: mails aka Conversations).

Since the ID remains the same, and people keep replying even after days, performing a simple
`datetime - datetime` (with same ConversationIDs) results in outputs such as `-1Day 20:05:01`, `-9Days` etc.

I just want to find the Response time of first reply to any mail, that enters the inbox.

(Sorry, cannot share Code).

Comment: There is `ConversationIndex` which, according to the documentation, sequences the emails within a conversation.  However, it is a long string which, as far as I can see, just encodes the dates associated with the email.  I think you will have to create an index to the emails based on the date received or sent and sort it.  `ConversationTopic` may also be useful.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, yah, that's exactly what I have planned. Instead of just `ConversationIndex`, I will use `1ConversationIndex` and `datetime` to identify specific mails.

Comment: @TonyDallimore, I found out a major problem here. Suppose : I receive a mail at 10:00 with ID: X11X, I reply to the mail at 11:00 (obviously same ID: X11X), how will You code to match these two ? I can filter for only one day both the IDs (received and sent) but that doesn't reflect the mails that you replied to after the day was over (next day). Any Suggestions ?

Comment: I use VBA and do not know what functionality is available with Python.  I have never tried using `ConversationId`.  My limited investigation suggests that Outlook is good at assigning the same `ConversationId` to every email in an exchange.  I would restrict on `ConversationId` and then sort.

Comment: Alternatively, I do not remember when I last received a reply that did not include the previous messages in the conversation.  I would search the body for “On Sat, 27 Jun 2020, 17:09 , <a.j.dallimore@myIsp.com> wrote:” or equivalent and link the emails myself.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Response Time from a Chain of Mails which all have **exactly the same** `ConversationID` (generated automatically by Outlook), I did the following:

I already had two Pandas DFs (let's say 'A' and 'B'), having the two columns each, namely:
`ConversationID` and `Time` (for received and sent mails).

Now,

1. Created a Pandas DataFrame 'C' with an inner join of 'A' and 'B' on `ConversationID'.
   (This gave me all the mails that I had replied to).
2. Sort the both the `Time` columns as "Ascending".
   (This brings the First Mail received and the First Mail replied to the top).
3. Now filter the new DataFrame 'C' on both `Time` columns with the condition,
   `Replied Mail Time > Received Mail Time`
   (Removes the -1 day outputs I was getting)
4. Groupby on `Received Mail Time` and use `.first()`
   (Finally giving a genuine response time, after calculating `Replied Mail Time - Received Mail Time`)